# Is There a way to capture a keydown event in an unresponsive form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form and it has a time consuming method that runs in it. I want to cancel that method with a keypress while it's running, however due to some limitations, i can not convert that method to a task or anything async.

The scenario is, user presses a button, the button calls that method *(lets say it runs a while(x > y)*) which has takes some, and if the user presses the esc key, i want to break that method.

How can I capture the keypress of an unresponsive form? Since while method blocks the form, keypress methods of the forms are unresponsive.

Comment: If it's unresponsive then you can't. Why is async limited to you? Could you use a background worker?

Comment: *Is There a way to capture a keydown event in an unresponsive form* **No** ... if you block main thread then no more messages are processed

Comment: You'd be better off finding out how to solve the issue that you "can not convert that method to a task or anything async". Why can't you?

Comment: Of course refactoring everything to async would do it, but the project scope doesnt allow that. time is the problem here

Comment: You need to use an instance of the form. The loop that is waiting for the key press must poll a status bit to exit when canceled.  The cancel method then must set the cancel bit.

Answer (score 1):

You can try calling `Application.DoEvents` from your time consuming method, but that will process also all kinds of messages, including dangerous ones like attempts to close the form, and so on.

Much better if you can rework your code and place our long-running method in a `BackgroundWorker`.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, it is unresponsive and will be unable to capture input.
Instead you can implement a background thread do your job there thus you can cancel thread as you want